# Can Ghidra load a directory and translate the binary files within it into assembly code?

Tags: ida, ghidra, reversing

Can Ghidra load a directory and automatically convert the binary files within it into assembly code? If not, is there a pre-defined script available, or do I need to write one myself? If Ghidra isn't suitable, do you recommend any other tools for this task besides objdump and IDA?

Comment: You might have seen this already, but Laurie has done a video on [Ghidra Scripting](https://youtu.be/z7SO6CF3guE?si=tRiO7RDG9DPDTaBs) which might be helpful.